# GOOGLE SHEETS - Arrayformula for duration between 2 datetime stamps ignoring weekends and our of hours time

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, nested-if, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to work out the duration of 2 date/time stamps, ignoring out-of-hours and weekends.  I have a formula that does individual durations (Column D) but when I try turning it into an array formula (Column E) it doesn't seem to work. I'm sure I have something slightly off and that is what is causing the issue.

I would greatly appreciate somebody taking a look at it.

Many thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NwDtnB9tyiJOAZHOKL7aSQnaMc4LpPIm7mGffPRKKcc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4:B=TRUE, MAP(A4:A100, C4:C100, 
 LAMBDA(A,C, (NETWORKDAYS(A,C)-1)*($C$1-$B$1)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(C,C),
 MEDIAN(MOD(C,1),$C$1,$B$1),$C$1)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(A,A)*MOD(A,1),$C$1,$B$1))), ))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great,  I did however forget to add the hours lunch that i would need to deduct from the duration this would be in cell B2(13:00) and C2(14:00).  Is this an easy fix, or would the Formula need an overhaul?

Comment: @WesleyHopkins share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output